# I need to switch to none-generated primary keys in EF 4.1

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I'm trying to sync two databases over the internet using Entity Framework 4.1 and WCF. My target database is used for a website and generates its own keys. When i sync i want to overwrite all data and keep the keys from my source database.

I already found out about the 'DatabaseGeneratedOption.None' annotation but that doesnt seem to work. I tried adding it runtime with the fluent API way but that doens't work either. When synchronizing i use a separate DbContext and the existing database.

is 'DatabaseGeneratedOption.None' only working when you Reinitialize your database? Or can you switch from identity seeding to none and back at runtime when using different contexts?

Can someone clear this out?

Thanx!

Comment: Whether or not your database generates Id values is solely dictated by the database itself (e.g. identity, or any other id generation routine). `DatabaseGeneratedOption` only _tells_ EF what the database is doing (and how EF should respond to that). You can try to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` `ON` by a sql query before inserting data to a table but I think that's pretty hard to integrate in the rest of your code. (Only one table at a time can have identity insert on).

Comment: Thanx for the info. i understand it better now. so no way of switching at runtime using the EF. I'm looking to go SQL style. That way i can switch the IDENTITY_INSERT for every table separately.